# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react-hooks

Tags: reactjs, api, methods, react-hooks

I'm a beginner. Thank you in advance for sharing your knowledge.

This error did not appear originally.

But even though they used the same code, it is now appearing.

What's the reason?

Although the data received through Api has the form of an array, the 'map' method does not work.

I read the other same question but I couldn't solve this problem.

This error bothered me for a day. Let me know what I have to do.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import styled from "styled-components";

const MyModal = ({ onClose, selectedItem }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  let id = selectedItem;
  let url = `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=${id}`;
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data.drinks);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [url]);
  return (
    <MyModals onClick={onClose}>
      <Wrapper>
        <button onClick={onClose}>X</button>
        {data.map((result) => {  This is the part of the problem.
          return (
            <Container>
              <Image>
                <img src={result.strDrinkThumb} alt={result.idDrink} />
              </Image>
              <About>
                <Name>{result.strDrink}</Name>
            </Container>
          );
        })}
      </Wrapper>
    </MyModals>
  );
};

export default MyModal;
```

Likewise, this file has the same problem. Errors appear and then appear.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Portal from "../Components/Portal";
import Modal from "../Components/Modal";

const Search = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("a");
  const [cocktails, setCocktails] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState("");

  const handleOpen = (idDrink) => {
    setSelectedItem(idDrink);
    setOpen(true);
    console.log("open");
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    console.log("close");
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const getDrinks = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${searchTerm}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setCocktails(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getDrinks();
    console.log("useEffect");
  }, [searchTerm]);

  return (
    <main style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <SearchForm setSearchTerm={setSearchTerm} />
      <Wrapper className="cocktail-list">
        {cocktails &&
          cocktails.drinks.map(({ idDrink, strDrink, strDrinkThumb }) => (
            <Container
              className="cocktail"
              onClick={() => {
                handleOpen(idDrink);
              }}
            >
              <Img>
                <img src={`${strDrinkThumb}`} alt={`${strDrink}`} />
              </Img>
              <Name key={`${idDrink}`}>{`${strDrink}`}</Name>
            </Container>
          ))}
      </Wrapper>
      {open && (
        <Portal>
          <Modal selectedItem={`${selectedItem}`} onClose={handleClose} />
        </Portal>
      )}
    </main>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Is there a problem with the part where I receive the Api data?

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Search from "./Search";
import Modal from "../Components/Modal";
import Portal from "../Components/Portal";

const Main = () => {
  const url = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php";
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUrl = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();
        setData(json);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    console.log("useEffect");
    fetchUrl();
  }, []);

  const handleOpen = (idDrink) => {
    setSelectedItem(idDrink);
    setOpen(true);
    console.log("open");
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    console.log("close");
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper className="main">
      {data &&
        data.drinks.map(({ idDrink, strDrink, strDrinkThumb }) => (
          <>
            <Container
              onClick={() => {
                handleOpen(idDrink);
                console.log(handleOpen(idDrink));
              }}
            >
              <img src={`${strDrinkThumb}`} alt={`${strDrink}`} />
              <div key={`${idDrink}`}>{`${strDrink}`}</div>
            </Container>
            {open && (
              <Portal>
                <Modal selectedItem={`${selectedItem}`} onClose={handleClose} />
              </Portal>
            )}
          </>
        ))}
      <Search />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
export default Main;
```

The error occurred in all files that wrote the 'map' method.

I really don't know what the problem is. Help me!

Comment: Looks like there was a case `res.data.drinks` which isn't an array so you might need to avoid set your list state in case of that instead showing as an error

Comment: `fetch` can reject under certain circumstances, you need to check for `response.ok` before accessing the JSON data. Have you checked your network tab that you are getting valid data? Are there any other errors before the react mapping error?

Comment: No, there were no other errors. As I checked on the console, [{...}] appears. The data is arrayed.

Comment: "checked on the console" What does this mean? You logged a valid response somewhere before updating state? What did you log & where?

Comment: I handled the error "//" and console.log.

Comment: FYI, valid responses can include `{ "drinks": null }`, so maybe check the response first and only update state if `drinks` is non-null. Same for the other GET requests. Try to ensure you don't mutate your state object types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has occurred because your map() called before the data come from API. So I will suggest first complete the API call and let the data came properly. Then you should map. You can use-

```
{data && data.map((result) => {  This will solve ur problem
      return (
        <Container>
          <Image>
            <img src={result.strDrinkThumb} alt={result.idDrink} />
          </Image>
          <About>
            <Name>{result.strDrink}</Name>
        </Container>
      );
    })}
```

Comment: Initial state for `data` is an empty array, so I don't quite think this is the resolution.

Comment: ```  
const fetchUrl = () => {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data.drinks);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUrl();
  }, []);
```  
Am I right to understand?

Comment: My code will resolve ur issue if the data came properly but as I can see https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=${id} is not return anything. Can you check the URL properly?

Comment: This is example id --> https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=14610

Answer (score 1):

Make sure of your data from API is a valid Array, you can check it with `Array.isArray()`.

Code could be like this:

```
{Array.isArray(data) &&
  data.map(result => (
    <Container>
      <Image>
        <img src={result.strDrinkThumb} alt={result.idDrink} />
      </Image>
      <About />
      <Name>{result.strDrink}</Name>
    </Container>
  ))}
```